# MySQL - select data from database between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have saved the dates of a user's registration as a datetime, so that's for instance **2011-12-06 10:45:36**. I have run this query and I expected this item - **2011-12-06 10:45:36** - will be selected:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE created_at >= '2011-12-01' AND
created_at <= '2011-12-06'
```

But is not. Exist any elegant way, how to select this item? As a first idea that I got was like `2011-12-06 + 1`, but this doesn't looks very nice.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your problem is that the short version of dates uses midnight as the default. So your query is actually:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= '2011-12-01 00:00:00' 
AND created_at <= '2011-12-06 00:00:00'
```

This is why you aren't seeing the record for 10:45.

Change it to:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users 
WHERE created_at >= '2011-12-01' 
AND created_at <= '2011-12-07'
```

You can also use:

```
SELECT users.* from users 
WHERE created_at >= '2011-12-01' 
AND created_at <= date_add('2011-12-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Which will select all users in the same interval you are looking for.

You might also find the BETWEEN operator more readable:

```
SELECT users.* from users 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN('2011-12-01', date_add('2011-12-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY));
```

Comment: If anyone else has problem with the last example, try the following syntax: `SELECT users.* from users 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND date_add('2011-12-01', INTERVAL 7 DAY);`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-07';
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use '2011-12-07' as the end point as a date without a time default to time 00:00:00.

So what you have actually written is interpreted as:

```
 SELECT users.* 
 FROM   users
 WHERE  created_at >= '2011-12-01 00:00:00' 
   AND  created_at <= '2011-12-06 00:00:00'
```

And your time stamp is: 2011-12-06 10:45:36 which is not between those points.
Change this too:

```
 SELECT users.* 
 FROM   users
 WHERE  created_at >= '2011-12-01'  -- Implied 00:00:00
   AND  created_at <  '2011-12-07'  -- Implied 00:00:00 and smaller than 
                                   --                  thus any time on 06
```

Comment: +1 I think we posted the same answer at exactly the same time :-)

Comment: @dash Actually Loki posted it half a minute earlier and his was supposed to be the accepted answer, but you were luckier. +1 for him for the faster answer, and +1 for you for giving him +1.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use `DATE()` function on the left hand operand as shown below

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried before and after rather than >= and <=?  Also, is this a date or a timestamp?

Comment: my bad, before and after are from something else.  for a timestamp you need to add a time as well as date as others have answered.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `created_at <= '2011-12-06'` will search for any records that where created at or before midnight on 2011-12-06
.  You want to search for `created_at < '2011-12-07'`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use in between better. It worked for me to get range then filter it

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL `DATE` function like below

For instance, if you want results between 2017-09-05 till 2017-09-09

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp_field) as date FROM stocks_annc WHERE DATE(timestamp_field) >= '2017-09-05' AND DATE(timestamp_field) <= '2017-09-09'
```

Make sure to wrap the dates within single quotation `''`

**Edit:**
A better solution would be this. It would make sure that it uses the index if any exists.

```
select date(timestamp_field) as date from stocks_annc where time_stamp_field >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and time_stamp_field <= '2022-01-10 00:00:00'
```

Hope this helps.