# how to select rows depending on the date today and due date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website which reminds users to pay their monthly dues via sms.

table: remind

```
Duedate              | BeforeDue
--------------------------------------------
27 Apr 2017 10:47 AM | 24 Apr 2017 10:47 AM
01 May 2017 10:46 AM | 28 Apr 2017 10:46 AM
```

I want to select all rows when today's date was between beforedue and duedate

i tried it but something is wrong with my codes

**$_POST[today] is formatted `date('d M Y h:i A')`**

```
$sq = "SELECT * FROM remind WHERE day3 BETWEEN '$_POST[today]' AND due";
$re = $conn->query($sq);

foreach($re as $row) {
    echo ' found: '.$row['day3'];
}
```

Comment: There are a few ways to do this depending on how your date value is stored: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458290/mysql-select-data-from-database-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

update your query like this:

`$sq = "SELECT * FROM remind WHERE day3 BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST[today]."', '%d %M %Y %h:%i%p')) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(Duedate, '%d %M %Y %h:%i%p'))";`