# How to compare time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a column of **Time** data type in mysql. I want to compare the time with a time string but don't know how to compare it. e.g., I want to know that some specific ***time is greater than 10:30:00***. How can I check it? I have this query but it is not showing any result although the data is available. what I am doing wrong?

```
select PK, userID, lr.Date, lr.Time, Half, lr.InOut, Op_UserID, About
from loginrecord lr
where lr.Date Between '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-17'
and lr.InOut = 1
and lr.Time > '10:30:00'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458290/mysql-select-data-from-database-between-two-dates see this hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the TIME_FORMAT function, like this:

```
select PK, userID, lr.Date, lr.Time, Half, lr.InOut, Op_UserID, About
from loginrecord lr
where lr.Date Between '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-17'
and lr.InOut = 1
and TIME_FORMAT(lr.Time, '%H:%i') > '10:30'
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
select PK, userID, lr.Date, lr.Time, Half, lr.InOut, Op_UserID, About
from loginrecord lr
where lr.Date Between '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-17'
and lr.InOut = 1
and lr.Time > CAST('10:30:00' AS time)
```

The CAST() function converts a value of any type into a value that has a specified type. The target type can be any one of the following types: BINARY, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, TIME,DECIMAL, SIGNED, UNSIGNED .

The CAST() function is often used to return a value with a specified type for comparison in the WHERE, JOIN, and HAVING clauses.

**[Reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/)**

Answer (score 1):

Also direct access to hour, minutes and seconds can be used to compare values

```
select PK, userID, lr.Date, lr.Time, Half, lr.InOut, Op_UserID, About
from loginrecord lr
where lr.Date Between '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-17'
and lr.InOut = 1
and HOUR(lr.Time) > 10
and MINUTE(lr.Time) > 30
and SECOND(lr.Time) > 00
```

For further information, please refer to [MYSQL Date and time funcitons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)