# Get data from last month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I checked [Get the records of last month in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server) and it did not work!

I try to get the records of last month based on my database table and column `issue_date`.

What's the SQL query to do this?

For clarification, today (27-April-18) I want to get all records from March-18.

I have the issue_date in the format that I convert to date but below code gives me all records from 01-March-2018 to and including today.

```
DATEPART(month, CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_header.issue_date,`1971/12/31`),106)) = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))
```

Comment: can you not get it by one month ago like following??
WHERE issue_date >= GETDATE()-30

Comment: -30 is for number of days wright. What I am trying to achieve is to have a code that will give me March data when run in April (every day - so it can not relay on days)

Comment: so you want data from 1st March to 31st March?

Comment: In this case yes. But in May it moves to 1st Apr to 30th Apr etc...always last month as per my question.

Comment: I think this post would give you an idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8458350/7100903

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the records of last month in SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424999/get-the-records-of-last-month-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I figured out is not pretty but it works. It first adds extra column with the month number to the **SELECT** portion of my code:

```
Month(CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_header.closing_date,'1971/12/31'),106))  As Month
```

And than is used for **WHERE** statement:

```
Month(CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_header.closing_date,'1971/12/31'),106)) = month(getdate())-1
```

So for anyone like me working in SQL report kind-of environment it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To get firstDay and lastDay of previous month

```
DECLARE @FirstDayOfLastMonth     DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 2))), DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 1))),
        @LastDayOfLastMonth      DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()))

        SELECT @FirstDayOfLastMonth, @LastDayOfLastMonth
```

Your required Query

```
 SELECT *
       FROM   TABLE
       WHERE  CAST(issue_date AS DATE) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 2))), DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 1))) AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks Ghazani. I am afraid I am not able to declare any variables. It is some kind of report designer environment that needs to start with select statement.

Comment: in second query, i did not used any variable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest method is `eomonth()`.  If there is no time component on `issuedate`:

```
where issuedate > eomonth(getdate(), -2) and
      issuedate <= eomonth(getdate(), -1)
```

If there is a time component:

```
where issuedate >= dateadd(day, 1, cast(eomonth(getdate(), -2) as date)) and
      issuedate < dateadd(day, 1, cast(eomonth(getdate(), -1) as date))
```

Without eomonth, I would do:

where issuedate < cast(dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate()) as date) and
      issuedate >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), getdate()) as date))

Comment: Still nil luck. The SQL hybrid I use is very restricted and eomonth is not available. What I try to do now is to exact the month from the date `(Month(CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_header.closing_date,`1971/12/31`),106)))` and add WHERE condition `(Month(CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_header.closing_date,`1971/12/31`),106)))' = '(Month(CONVERT (VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(day,wo_header.closing_date,`1971/12/31`),106)))' - 1`. It is not working yet thou.