# Hi there I want to fetch record Between to dates

Tags: php, sql

I want to fetch records from the DB from one date to the second I have to fetch records but it's not giving me a record of the last date.

```html
$query =  "SELECT `date_of_info_added` , `sub_source` FROM `jcontacts` where date_of_info_added  >= $month and date_of_info_added <= $end ORDER BY date_of_info_added DESC";
```

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458290/mysql-select-data-from-database-between-two-dates)

Comment: What are the actual contents of $month and $end?

(Also: you may want to consider using the BETWEEN...AND operator. It is not really functionally different, but IMHO way more readable)

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

Comment: $month = strtotime($start."-01-01");
  $end =  strtotime($end."-12-31");

Comment: These are two variable i am trying to get the record of the whole year

Comment: I have tried between but got the same results.

Comment: Actually, it's not giving me the record of 31 Dec

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this... use between.

```
$query = "SELECT date_of_info_added , sub_source FROM jcontacts WHERE date_of_info_added BETWEEN '$month' AND '$end' ORDER BY date_of_info_added DESC"
```

Comment: $month = strtotime($start."-01-01");
  $end =  strtotime($end."-12-31");
Actually it's not giving me the record of 31 Dec date

Comment: where is the year from your sample? what is the value of $month and $end?

Comment: I didn't use year its working fine without year but not giving me the data of 31 dec

Comment: another way is you might want to add time for the end.... $end = $end." 23:59:59"; or the latest time you want based on now.