# How to skip days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am creating a report where I have to show last 7 days data and previous 7 days data. But I can fetch last 7 days data but for previous 7 days I don't know how to write the sql!

Suppose today is 14th March. I am fetching data from database for last 7 days which is 8th March to 14th March is,

```sql
WHERE my_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

But how to write the sql for previous 7 days? Which is 1st March to 7th March.
I have tried this,

```sql
WHERE my_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) and NOW()
```

I don't think it's working! How am I going to get data for 1st March to 7th March and skip 8th March to 14th March?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - select data from database between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458290/mysql-select-data-from-database-between-two-dates)

Comment: No, its saying between two dates but I want previous 7 days and skip last 7 days.

Comment: Provide an example as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output (for 2, not 7, days, for to decrease the source rows amount needed).

Comment: Does `WHERE my_date CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 8 DAY` solves?

Comment: Do I have to put any operator between `my_date [ HERE ] CURRENT_DATE -  INTERVAL 14 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 8 DAY `? if no then it's generating error.

Comment: @Alaindeseine answer is working perfectly. Do I have to edit my question anymore?

Comment: What type is my_date?

Comment: @ysth `timestamp`

Comment: ah, then the question is do you want calendar days or exactly 14 days ago from the time it is now to a week later than that?  if calendar days, use current_date, otherwise use now()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try this :

```
WHERE my_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) and DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```