# Processing millions of data records with PHP MySQL issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have run into a delayed processing time for a PHP program,
I have a MySQL record with over 1000 tables;
Each table is created once a new device is added, e.g assets_data_imeixx - to assets_data_imeixx1000th table

Each table contains about 45,000 rows of records inserted every 10 seconds,
Below is my PHP code to query the database and fetch all these records based on datetime.

Issue: The program executes without error but it takes about 1.3minutes to 4mins for very large records.

PHP Code:

```
$ms = mysqli connection string in config.php //$ms is OKAY
$user_id = '5';
$q = "SELECT * FROM `user_assets` WHERE `user`='".$user_id ."' ORDER BY `imei` ASC";
    
$r = mysqli_query($ms,$q);
$result = array(); //$result array to contain all data

while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    
//fetch 7 days record
    for ($i=1; $i < 7; $i++) { 
        $date = "-" . $i . " days";
        $days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date, strtotime('today')));
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM assets_data_" . $row["imei"] . " WHERE dt_time LIKE '" . $days_ago .  "%' LIMIT 1"; // its correct
    
        //$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
        $result1 = mysqli_query($ms,$sql1);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
        echo $row['imei']." ".$row2['dt_server']."<br/>";
   }
}
```

Above code fetches over 1000 devices from **user_assets** table, These IMEI each has its own table that contains over 45,000 records in each table of location data.
The *for loop* iterates over each IMEI table and records.
[image: SQL SELECT sample data]
Above code runs without error but take so much time to complete, I want to find a solution to optimize and have code execute in a very short time max 5 seconds.
I need help and suggestions on optimizing and running this large scale of data and iteration.
[image: Program execution]

[image: Run time delay]

(from Comment)

```
CREATE TABLE gs_object_data_863844052008346 (
    dt_server datetime NOT NULL, 
    dt_tracker datetime NOT NULL, 
    lat double DEFAULT NULL, 
    lng double DEFAULT NULL, 
    altitude double DEFAULT NULL, 
    angle double DEFAULT NULL, 
    speed double...
```

```
(From Comment)
gs_object_data_072101424612
gs_object_data_072101425049
gs_object_data_072101425486
gs_object_data_072101445153
gs_object_data_111111111111111
gs_object_data_1234567894
gs_object_data_222222222222222
gs_object_data_2716325849
gs_object_data_2716345818
gs_object_data_30090515907
gs_object_data_3009072323
gs_object_data_3009073758
gs_object_data_352093088838221
gs_object_data_352093088839310
gs_object_data_352093088840045
gs_object_data_352121088128697
gs_object_data_352121088132681
gs_object_data_352621109438959
gs_object_data_352621109440203
gs_object_data_352625694095355
gs_object_data_352672102822186
gs_object_data_352672103490900
gs_object_data_352672103490975
gs_object_data_352672103490991
gs_object_data_352887074794052
gs_object_data_352887074794102
gs_object_data_352887074794193
gs_object_data_352887074794417
gs_object_data_352887074794425
gs_object_data_352887074794433
gs_object_data_352887074794441
gs_object_data_352887074794458
gs_object_data_352887074794474
gs_object_data_352887074813696
gs_object_data_352887074813712
gs_object_data_352887074813720
gs_object_data_352887074813753
gs_object_data_352887074813761
gs_object_data_352887074813803
```

- 900+ tables each having different location data.
  **Requirement:** Loop through each table, fetch data for selected date range say:
  `"SELECT dt_server FROM gs_object_data_" . $row["imei"] . " WHERE dt_server BETWEEN '2022-02-05 00:00:00' AND '2022-02-12 00:00:00'";`

**Expected Result:** Return result set containing data from **each** table containing information for the selected date range. That means having 1000 tables will have to be looped through each table and also fetch data in each table.

Comment: Are your date/times stored as dates on the database or strings?

Comment: You need to read on execution plans and indexing

Comment: @NigelRen, dt_time is stored as DATETIME on the database

Comment: Then why do you use `LIKE`, which operates on strings?

Comment: @Olivier, The date format is as soon above, Check first image,`dt_server` is `2022-02-27 02:50:20`, I am interested in search for just the day not with the time. I am interested in searching for just `2022-02-27`

Comment: So for 7 days, create two dates with start and end date/times and fetch all records between that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458290/mysql-select-data-from-database-between-two-dates)

Comment: *"I am interested in searching for just the day not with the time"* That doesn't change the fact that `LIKE` forces MySQL to convert the datetime to a string, which makes it unable to use an index, which forces it to scan the entire table, which is slow.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with KIKO -- 1 table not 1000.  But, if I understand the rest, there are really 2 or 3 main tables.

Looking at your PHP -- It is often inefficient to look up one list, then go into a loop to find more.  The better way (perhaps 10 times as fast) is to have a single `SELECT` with a `JOIN` to do both selects at once.

Consider some variation of this MySQL syntax; it may avoid most of the PHP code relating to `$days_ago`:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

After also merging the Selects, this gives you the rows for the last 7 days:

```
WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

(I did not understand the need for `LIMIT 1`; please explain.)

Yes, you can use `DATETIME` values as strings, but try not to.  Usually DateTime functions are more efficient.

Consider "composite" indexes:

```
INDEX(imei, dt)
```

which will be very efficient for

```
WHERE imei = $imei
  AND dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

I would ponder ways to have less redundancy in the output; but that should mostly be done *after* fetching the raw data from the table(s).

Turn on the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) with a low value of `long_query_time`; it will  help you locate the worst query; then we can focus on it.

An IMEI is up to 17 characters, always digits?  If you are not already using this, I suggest `BIGINT` since it will occupy only 8 bytes.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the main tables.

Comment: What is the Primary Key of those tables? What indexes do you have?

Comment: `DOUBLE` is overkill for most values.  `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes instead of 8 and has more than enough precision.

Comment: There is no Primary Key of these tables, Only READ ONLY is required from the initial design concept, No ID nothing. I think `FLOAT` will make a better adjustment

Comment: Some form of index is useful for performance is an issue.  If you go with the "1 table" approach, you will certainly need index(es).

Comment: Sorry I missed out, the index column is the `dt_tracker` column, I missed it on my previous comment. Right now I am looking for best possible option to improve peformance as each table contains different data. And there is a need to retrieve information from each of the table, Taking "1 table" approach will help understand how to extend it to as many tables as required

Comment: @NzelumMayorChukwuebuka - Currently you need `INDEX(dt_server)`.  With the 1-table approach, you will need `INDEX(imai, dt_server)`.  More likely, that should be `PRIMARY KEY` (if the dt has no dups for a given imai)

Answer (score 0):

Since all those 1000 tables are the same it would make sense to put all that data into 1 table. Then partition that table on date, use proper indexes, and optimize the query.

See: [Normalization of Database](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Since you limit results to one user, and one row per device, it should be possible to execute a query in well below one second.

Comment: The result is a sample result for one user,
A single user can have up to 1000 devices linked to account, for this example I am dealing with a single user with 1000 device IMEI,
Now the IMEI creates a new table like `asset_data_IMEI`, so for this user there will be additional 1000 tables created for each IMEI.
Each table like `asset_data_IMEI` contains real-time records of about 45,000 records each which are different in all of them but the columns are same.
I am iterating through each 1000 tables and 45,000+ records

Comment: @NzelumMayorChukwuebuka I think that was already explained your question. Are you saying that this is what you do, and you're unwilling to change anything? If that is the case then you'll have to accept longer execution times.